# Export to Excel/csv by SQL query statement regularly on Windows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-excel, timing

I use Oracle and I would like to export some data to Excel/csv by SQL query statement regularly on Windows, SQL query statement as below:

```
SELECT A.e,
       a.f,
       a.g,
       b.h
FROM A 
JOIN C ON C.e=A.e
JOIN B ON C.j=B.j;
```

Thanks so much for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for Windows test_csv.bat

```
sqlplus -s  user/password@net_alias  @csv.sql
```

csv.sql

```
    set heading off
    set termout OFF
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET TAB OFF
    set pause off
    set verify off
    SET UNDERLINE OFF
    set trimspool on
    set timing off
    set echo off
    set linesize 1000
    set pagesize 0
    SET COLSEP ';'
    spool test.csv
    SELECT A.e,
       a.f,
       a.g,
       b.h
   FROM A 
   JOIN C ON C.e=A.e
   JOIN B ON C.j=B.j; 
    spool off
    exit;
```